# Ruby2d doesn't start on windows 7

Tags: ruby, ruby2d

I tried installing ruby2d on Windows 10 and it works perfectly, but when I try to install on my old PC that is on Windows 7, it installs in Gemfile but it doesn't work.

This error shows up:

`'require': cannot load such file -- ruby2d (LoadError)`